# How to link Node.js Post script to HTML form?

Tags: html, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I have created a REST full APi, which works as I would be expecting if I am running Postman. I run the Test from an index.js file which would have the routes saved as per below file.

```
const config = require('config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const users = require('./routes/users');
const auth = require('./routes/auth');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//mongoose.set();

if (!config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))
{
  console.log('Fatal ERRORR: jwtPrivateKey key is not defined')
  process.exit(1);
}

mongoose.connect(uri ,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
  })
.then(()=>console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
.catch(err=> console.log('Not Connected, bad ;(', err));

app.use(express.json());
//THis is only for posting the user, e.g. Registering them
app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/auth', auth);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

The real code is happening here. Testing this in Postmon I could establish, that the values are saved in MongoDB.

```
 router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    //validates the request.
    const { error } = validate(req.body); 
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
   

    let user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if (user)  return res.status(400).send('User Already Register, try again!');
  
    user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ['firstName','lastName','email','password','subscription']));
   
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(15);
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
   
    //Here the user is being saved in the Database.
    await user.save();    

    //const token = user.generateAuthToken();
    
    //const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
    const token = user.generateAuthToken();
    //We are sending the authentication in the header, and the infromation back to client
    res.header('x-auth-token',token).send( _.pick(user, ['_id','firstName','lastName','email','subscription']));
});
```

Now my question's are:

1. How can I call the second code block from a , in one particular html file. When using Action="path to the users.js", the browser opens the js file code but doesn't do anything.
2. Do I need to rewrite the Post block part so that it would as well include the connection details to the DB? And would this mean I would keep open the connection to MongoDB once I insert Read etc.? Wouldn't this eat a lot of resources if multiple users would e.g. log in at the same time?
3. Or is there a way how I can use the index.js + the users.js which is refereed in the index.js file together?

All of these are theoretical questions, as I am not quite sure how to use the created API in html, then I created as walking through a tutorial.

Do I need to change the approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some longs hours I finally understood my own issue and question.

What I wanted to achieve is from an HTML page post data in MongoDB through API (this I assume is the best way how to describe this).
In order to do this I needed to:

1. Start server for the API function e.g. nodemon index.js, which has the information regarding the API.

- Opened VS Code opened the terminal and started the API server (if I can call it like that)
- Opened CMD and startet the local host for the index.html with navigating to it's folder and then writting http-server now I could access this on http://127.0.0.1:8080.

2. For the register.html in the form I needed to post:

This is the part which I didn't understood, but now it makes sense. Basically I start the server API seperatly and once it is started I can use e.g. Postmon and other apps which can access this link. I somehow thought html needs some more direct calls.

So After the localhost is started then the register.html will know where to post it via API.

Now I have a JOI validate issue, though on a different more simple case this worked, so I just need to fix the code there.

Thank You For reading through and Apologize if was not clear, still learning the terminology!